# Unlist dataframe produces unexpected outcome

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, character

Please kindly help with the issue why the code below produces vector ("1", "1") instead of expected ("1", "string") and how to fix it. Thank you.

```
data<-c("string")

data<-data.frame(lapply(data, type.convert), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

colnames(data)<-c("Choice")

data<-rownames_to_column(data)

last_columns<-colnames(data)    

columns_without_first<-last_columns[2:length(last_columns)]

converted_data<-as.character(unlist(data[1,]))

print(converted_data)
```

Comment: Can you include your data using `dput` so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: As you can see data is simply a character vector containing "string": data<-c("string"). Why question was down voted? It has all the necessary info. Just copy paste and run the code and get the unexpected output.

Comment: I'm not sure what your code is trying to achieve exactly as it seems quite roundabout but the issue is in the use of `type.convert` where character is converted to a factor. You can prevent this by using the `as.is = TRUE` argument.  Perhaps if you outline your ultimate goal you can get advice on a more efficient approach.

Comment: Required output: converted_data<-c('1', 'string'); Current output: converted_data<-c('1', '1'). How to get required output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because your `Choice` argument is `factor`. When you do

```
data<-c("string")
data<-data.frame(lapply(data, type.convert), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
colnames(data)<-c("Choice")

str(data)
#'data.frame':  1 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ Choice: Factor w/ 1 level "string": 1
```

Instead do

```
data<-c("string")
data <- data.frame(Choice = data, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

str(data)
#'data.frame':  1 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ Choice: chr "string"
```

So after you perform rest of the steps, you will get your expected output.

```
data<- tibble::rownames_to_column(data)
last_columns<-colnames(data)    
columns_without_first<-last_columns[2:length(last_columns)]
converted_data<-as.character(unlist(data[1,]))

converted_data
#[1] "1"      "string"
```

Answer (score 0):

If we do the `as.is`, it would be `character`

```
data <- c("string")
data <- data.frame(lapply(data, type.convert, as.is = TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
colnames(data) <- "Choice"
str(data)
#'data.frame':  1 obs. of  1 variable:
#$ Choice: chr "string"
```

---

Or another option is `retype` from `hablar`

```
library(hablar)
data <- c("string")
data.frame(data) %>% 
     retype
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#   data  
#  <chr> 
#1 string
```